# How parse URL string whitout sscanf

Tags: c

I have problem whit parsing of URL (example http://user:pass@example.com:6379/8?client_name=itisme&timeout=0.5&timeout_connect=0.25)
and i need this output or similar
output:

```
TCP = http
user = user
password = pass
host = example.com
port = 6379
number = 8 
array of parametrs = {"client_name","itisme", "timeout","0.5","timeout_connect","0.25"}
```

Is there better way then using strtok() and huge switch/case?

Here: is my function for parsing, I can get as input parametr Url with user and pass or whitout that.

```
Conn_Properties ConnProp(char *URL)
{
  Conn_Properties result;
  bool Password = false;
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<strlen(URL);++i)
  {
      if (URL[i]=='@')
      {
         Password = true;
         break;
      }
  }
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (URL,"@:/?");
  int cnt_loop = 1;
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    switch (cnt_loop)
    {
        case 1:
            result.TCPconn = pch;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (Password)
                if (strcmp(result.TCPconn,"redis")==0)
                    result.user = pch;
            if (strcmp(result.TCPconn,"redis+sentinel")==0 && Password)
                            result.Sentinel_pass = pch;
            break;
        case 3:
            if (strcmp(result.TCPconn,"redis+sentinel")==0 && Password)
                result.Sentinel_pass = pch;
            if (strcmp(result.TCPconn,"redis")==0 && Password)
                result.Redis_pass = pch;
            break;
        case 4:
            result.DNS_name = pch;
            break;
        case 5:
            result.DNS_port = pch;
            break;
        case 6:
            result.DB_number = pch;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    switchstr(pch) {
        casestr("client_type")
            result.client_type = strtok (NULL,"=&");
            break;
        casestr("client_name")
            result.client_name = strtok (NULL,"=&");
            break;
        casestr("password")
            result.Redis_pass = strtok (NULL,"=&");
            break;
        casestr("timeout")
            pch = strtok (NULL,"=&.");
            result.timeout = TValcreator(pch);
            result.timeout_present = true;
            break;
        casestr("timeout_connect")
            pch = strtok (NULL,"=&.");
            result.timeout_conn= TValcreator(pch);
            result.timeout_conn_present = true;
            break;
        casestr("db")
            result.DB_number = strtok (NULL,"=&");
            break;
        casestr("service_name")
            result.service_name = strtok (NULL,"=&");
            break;
        casestr("accessmode")
            result.accessmode = strtok (NULL,"=&");
            break;
        casestr("accesstestkey")
            result.accesstestkey = strtok (NULL,"=&");
            break;
        casestr("stimeout")
            pch = strtok (NULL,"=&");
            result.stimeout = TValcreator(pch);
            result.stimeout_present = true;
            break;
        casestr("stimeout_result")
            pch = strtok (NULL,"=&.");
            result.stimeout_result= TValcreator(pch);
            result.stimeout_result_present = true;
            break;
        defaultstr
            break;
    } switchstr_end;
      pch = strtok (NULL, "@:/?%=&");
      if (Password && (cnt_loop==1 || cnt_loop==2))
          ++cnt_loop;
      else
          if (!Password && cnt_loop==1)
              cnt_loop = 4;
          else
              if (!Password && cnt_loop>=3)
                   ++cnt_loop;
              else
                  ++cnt_loop;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at libcurl ([this example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/parseurl.html) in particular)

Comment: Hi Jan, could you add the code you tried so far and highlight what's not working, what problems you encountered?

Comment: As a general rule, the `strspn` - `strcspn` pair is both more versatile and robust (no static data, no modification of the source string) than `strtok`...

Comment: `switchstr(pch) {
        casestr("client_type")` <<-- Syntax error. Are you using C?

Comment: i have defined macro for that  :D

#define switchstr(x) \
    { char *__sw = (x); bool __done = false; bool __cont = false; \
        regex_t __regex; regcomp(&__regex, ".*", 0); do {

#define casestr(x)    } if ( __cont || !strcmp ( __sw, x ) ) \
                        { __done = true; __cont = true;

#define defaultstr    } if ( !__done || __cont ) {

#define switchstr_end } while ( 0 ); regfree(&__regex); }